# pyspark compatible hadoop aws and aws adk for version 2.4.4

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to read and write from s3 buckets using pyspark with the help of these two libraries from maven https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.7 and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4  which are really old. I tried with the different combinations of hadoop-aws and aws-java-SDK but it's not working with the pyspark version 2.4.4 . does anyone know which versions of Hadoop and java SDK's are compatible with spark version 2.4.4?

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following:

```
Spark: 2.4.4
Hadoop: 2.7.3
Haddop-AWS: hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
AWS-JAVA-SDK: aws-java-sdk-1.7.3.jar
Scala: 2.11
```

Works for me and use `s3a://bucket-name/`

(**Note**: For PySPark I used `aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar`) because I wasn't able to use

```
df.write.csv(path=path, mode="overwrite", compression="None")
```

Comment: i am using the same versions of jar files, but they are pretty old. i was thinking about the newer versions